# Enumerate labels in text circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, enumerate, paralist

I am trying to get enumerations with the list labels surrounded by text circles for which I am using the following code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\mycirc[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt](C) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

I am trying to get the following code to work:

```
    \begin{compactenum}[{\mycirc{}A{}}]
    \item
    \end{compactenum}
```

but no luck yet. Note that `compactenum` comes from the `paralist` package. Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend you use the `enumitem` package for your compact list.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*\mycirc[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=3ex](C) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt,label=\protect\mycirc{\Alph*}]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item
  \item
  \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 12):

If you still want to use `paralist`, a bit of trickery is needed as unfortunately `paralist` doesn't seem to offer a means for constructing custom labels:

```
\def\mycirc\csname#1\endcsname{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
\node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt](C) {\csname#1\endcsname};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

and then

```
\begin{compactenum}[\mycirc A]
```

Comment: Ah, I like both your solution and Alan's. But I think I am going to go with Alan's because it seems simpler to me! :) Thanks though.