# Unwanted line spacing inside lstlisting, inside enumerate

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, enumerate

I want to place some code inside of an `enumerate` whose labels are encircled letters. I'm following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49194/enumerate-labels-in-text-circles) to get the encircled letter labels, but I'm having a spacing issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\tt}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\circlabel[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=4ex](C) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circlabel{$\Alph*$}]
    \item
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,gobble=12]
            int someCode = 0;
            int onMultipleLines = 1;
            int likeThis = 2;
        \end{lstlisting}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get rid of the space between the first and second lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the `overlay` option for the `tikzpicure`, so it doesn't take space and adjust `labelsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\tt}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\circlabel[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base),overlay]
        \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=4ex](C) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circlabel{$\Alph*$},labelsep=15pt]
    \item
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,gobble=12]
            int someCode = 0;
            int onMultipleLines = 1;
            int likeThis = 2;
        \end{lstlisting}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also added `leftmargin=50pt` to prevent the labels from spilling into the left page margin (since `labelsep` pushes the labels to the left, rather than pushing the content to the right).