# Circling letter in \item[] in the \itemize environment

Tags: itemize, characters, circles

When I want to circle number 1-10, I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{192}] text
\item[\textcolor{red}{\ding{183}}] \tt text
\item[\ding{194}] \it text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

producing the output

[image]

but I can't do `0`,`11-infty` or letters.

Any help or a point in the right direction. I've seen other posts. But the solutions are cumbersome or can't be used in the `\item[]` and probably definitely can't be colored.

Mon.Nov 29,2021 9:54pmPST update using a solution from `Good way to make \textcircled numbers?` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8473

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]    {\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize} 
\item[\circled{0}] text
\item[\circled{a}] \bf text
\item[\textcolor{red}{\circled{b}}] \tt how to fill like this $\to$ {\Large\textcolor{red}{\ding{183}}}
\item[\textcolor{Green}{\circled{\bf c}}] \it text
\item[\textcolor{blue}{\circled{$\mathcal{P}$}}]$\mathcal{TEXT}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

producing
[image]

it does everything I need for now. But I can't fill the circle.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [Enumerate labels in text circles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49194/5764); [Good way to make `\textcircled` numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/5764)

Comment: Ah yes. it does most of what I need right now thank you