# How to use the enumerate function to label the items in circled numbers?

Tags: enumerate, labels

I want to typeset a piece of document containing this format:

[image]

I know that it can be done by adding each label separately using `pitfont`, but I have too many of the labelled items and typesetting each and aligning them is a hard job. I wonder if this can be done through customizing the `enumerate` function.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are already quite a number of answers on this site that tackle similar problems: for example, [①](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50446/47927), [②](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590834/47927), [③](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49194/47927) and [④](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/47927). Maybe these can help you getting started.

Comment: @JasperHabicht ⓝ ⓘ ⓒ ⓔ :-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with `enumitem` and the `circledsteps` packages:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{circledsteps}

    \begin{document}

      \begin{enumerate}[label = \Circled{\arabic*}, font=\sffamily]
        \item Test
        \item Another test
        \item Still another test
        \item A last test
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can say:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\protected\def\circled#1{%
\tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor = base,inner sep = 0pt,draw,circle]{#1};}%
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label = \circled{\arabic*}]
    \item test
    \item test
    \begin{enumerate}[label = \circled{\roman*}]
      \item test
      \item test
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]